# Cisco IOS Privilege Escalation Vulnerability Workaround

Tags: cisco

[For this Cisco vulnerability that they have discovered](https://sec.cloudapps.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-iosxe-webui-privesc-j22SaA4z) it states that

> If the **ip http server** command is present and the configuration
> also contains **ip http active-session-modules none**, the
> vulnerability is not exploitable over HTTP.
>
> If the **ip http secure-server** command is present and the
> configuration also contains **ip http secure-active-session-modules
> none**, the vulnerability is not exploitable over HTTPS.

Then later on the page it says

> Workarounds - There are no workarounds that address this vulnerability.

Does that mean that you cant just add the config below to get rid of the vulnerability?

> ip http secure-active-session-modules none
>
> ip http active-session-modules none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "no workaround", they mean "no workaround". The only way to mitigate the problem is to disable the http/https service, or effectively break it by turning off all the session-modules.

If you trust your internal networks, an ACL blocking 80(http) and 443(https) on internet facing interfaces will block the attack. But, if they get beyond your security perimeter, your network is still open to this attack.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand the significance of ip http active-session-modules none, i have turned the whole http secure-server off